# Как добавить обертку тегу iframe?

Tags: wordpress

Скажите как добавить обертку тегy iframe, я хочу сделать responsive обертку для тега, если я кидаю iframe с youtube в тело поста на выходе получается iframe обернутый в тег p, можно ли его оборачивать например в div.responsive-wrapper ?

Comment: Вообще-то ВП сам понимает ссылки с ютуба. Не надо вставлять никаких ифреймов без особой надобности. см https://codex.wordpress.org/%D0%92%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8A%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот так делается адаптивная верстка под `youtube`. `padding-bottom: 56.25%` вычисляется исходя из соотношения сторон видео. В данном случае 16x9. Расчет производится так:

```
9/16*100% = 56.25%
```

```css
#video {
  width: 70%;
  margin: auto;
}
.video-container {
  position: relative;
  padding-bottom: 56.25%;
  height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.video-container iframe {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="video">
  <div class="video-container">
    <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/WlnexV2eAvI" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen>
    </iframe>
  </div>
</div>
```

**UPDATE:**

Вывести в тексте поста адаптивный `iframe` можно через свой шорткод. Следующий код надо добавить в `functions.php`:

```
function youtube_shortcode($atts) {
    ob_start();
    ?>
        <div id="video">
            <div class="video-container">
                <iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/<?php echo $atts['src']; ?>" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen>
                </iframe>
            </div>
        </div>
    <?php
    return ob_get_clean();
}
add_shortcode('youtube', 'youtube_shortcode');
```

В тексте поста надо вставить: `[youtube src="WlnexV2eAvI"]`

Работающий пример [здесь](http://test.kagg.eu/so623611/).

Comment: Это понятно, но как мне вывести .video-container

Comment: Автоматом в теле статьи тег iframe оборачивается тегом p, я же не буду добавлять теги в пост, это как-то не курто. Я хочу просто кинуть iframe в тело статью но на выходе получить его обернутым в .video-container

Comment: Ну вы хотите, чтобы WordPress все сделал сам каким-то чудесным образом. Так не бывает. Не хотите вставлять теги руками - напишите свой шорткод и вставляйте youtube ролик в тело поста примерно таким образом:

[youtube src="WlnexV2eAvI"]

Comment: Ну чего сам )) я думал через functions как-то можно, допустим можно же вырезать тег p что-бы iframe был сам по себе значит можно как-то и добавить.

Comment: вырезать можно так: function strip_ptags_on_iframe($content)
{
    return preg_replace('/<p>\s*(<iframe.*>*.<\/iframe>)\s*<\/p>/iU', '\1', $content);
}
add_filter('the_content', 'strip_ptags_on_iframe');  Как добавить не знаю. Ну да можно через шорткод.

Comment: ок, сейчас дополню ответ функцией шорткода

Comment: спасибо попробую тогда через шорткод

Comment: дополнил ответ шорткодом

Comment: спасибо , понятно, на основании этого шорткода сделаю наверное еще пару для vimeo итд.