# Как добавить #document в <iframe>?

Tags: javascript, html, frontend

Просмотрел все похожие вопросы.

[Как разместить html в iframe](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/848714/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-html-%D0%B2-iframe)

[Как добавить обертку тегу iframe?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/623611/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%82%D0%BA%D1%83-%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B3%D1%83-iframe)

и.т.д

У меня похожий вопрос и вариант с добавление #document в iframe 
у меня прекрасно работает.

```
  let iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
  iframe.className = "webconteiner";
  iframe.height = '100%'
  iframe.width = '100%'
  console.assert(false, iframe )
  document['body'].appendChild(iframe)
  let iframeDoc = iframe.contentDocument || 
  iframe.contentWindow.document;
  iframeDoc.open();
  iframeDoc.write(body);
  iframeDoc.close();
  console.assert(false, iframe)
```

Но мне как раз требуется добавить #document в iframe
до того, как я добавлю iframe на страницу сайта.

Создавая отдельно документ у меня схожая последовательность действий не работает.
contentDocument остаётся пустым.

Подскажите, что я делаю не так ?

Comment: зачем это нужно?

Comment: Я в js формирую сам документ, которым мне требуется подменить содержимое уже существующего iframe к которому у меня нет доступа.

Comment: Если iframe с другого домена, то менять его содержимое запрещено политикой безопасности браузера

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если `iframe` с другого домена, то менять его содержимое запрещено политикой безопасности браузера.

Ограничение **Same Origin** ограничивает доступ окон и фреймов друг к другу, а также влияет на AJAX-запросы к серверу.

Причина, по которой оно существует – безопасность. Если есть два окна, в одном из которых `vasya-pupkin.com`, а в другом `gmail.com`, то мы бы не хотели, чтобы скрипт из первого мог читать нашу почту.

Два URL считаются имеющим один источник («same origin»), если у них одинаковый протокол, домен и порт.

Эти URL имеют один источник:

```
http://site.com
http://site.com/
http://site.com/my/page.html
```

А вот эти – все из других источников:

```
http://www.site.com (другой домен)
http://site.org (другой домен)
https://site.com (другой протокол)
http://site.com:8080 (другой порт)
```

Взято [отсюда](https://learn.javascript.ru/same-origin-policy)

Comment: Дак а я не лезу в чужой iframe я его удаляю, мне свой сформировать надо до того как я его добавлю.

Comment: @СергейЗабабурин а нельзя добавить еще один а не менять тот?

Comment: Ну в примере то что я привёл так и делается. Всё работает.
Минус в том что экран мерцает на пару долесекунд. Я это убрать хочу

Comment: Вы можете убрать iframe css-ом и показать когда все загрузится

Comment: Точно, не подумал. Сегодня сделаю.  Но мне но про формирование документа всё же почитаю ещё, интересно стало чем документ на странице отличается от документа созданного в js (у меня библиотека врапер над iframe интересная очень, хотелось бы туда интегрировать сразу же вставку)